# How do I mock parameters and tagdata when using testee?

Tags: ee2, add-on-development

I've gotten as far as getting a tag to run with it's default parameters, but I have no clue on how to fake the passing of parameters and tagdata.

I've checked the documentation for testee and munged a bit through it's own tests. I realize it is an unsupported addon as the author has moved away from ExpressionEngine, but that is why I am asking here.

Here's a working test so far:

```
public function test__returns_zero_with_default_attributes() {

    $result = $this->_subject->modulo();
    $this->assertEqual($result, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it works this way:

```
$this->_subject->EE->TMPL->returns('fetch_param', 11, array('numerator', '1'));
```

This says when the mock EE object receives a call to fetch_param with the arguments 'numerator' and '1' (`$this->EE->fetch_param('numerator', '1')` in the plugin code) return the value 11.

Similar can be done for the tagdata property:

```
$this->_subject->EE->tagdata = 'This is text simulating the contents of a tag pair';
```

Voila! Now you can test module and plugin tags.